# BigQuery - Shopping Behavior Funnel + Landing Page

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I created following query to replicate a standard UA report on the session level:

```
SELECT
  `date` AS date,
  (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.hostname, r'^something\.com$') THEN page.hostname
    ELSE
    'Other'
  END
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits)
  WHERE
    isentrance = TRUE) AS hostname,
  CASE
    WHEN totals.newvisits = 1 THEN 'New visitor'
  ELSE
  'Returning visitor'
END
  AS user_type,
  device.deviceCategory AS device_category,
  trafficsource.source AS source,
  trafficsource.medium AS medium,
  trafficsource.campaign AS campaign,
  (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'(?i)\?variant=') THEN page.pagepath
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'(?i)\?') THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagepath,r'(?:\?|&)((?:[^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))', '')
      WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'(?i)#') THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(page.pagepath,r'#.*', '')
    ELSE
    page.pagepath
  END
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits)
  WHERE
    isentrance = TRUE) AS landing_page,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE
        WHEN totals.newvisits = 1 THEN fullvisitorid
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      )) AS new_users,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) AS sessions,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN totals.bounces = 1 THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS bounces,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pages,
  SUM(totals.timeonsite) AS timeonsite,
  ifnull(SUM(totals.transactions),
    0) AS transactions,
  ifnull(SUM(totals.totaltransactionrevenue),
    0)/1000000 AS revenue,
FROM
  `analytics-12345.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  totals.visits = 1
  AND _table_suffix = '20220821'
GROUP BY
  date,
  hostname,
  user_type,
  device_category,
  source,
  medium,
  campaign,
  landing_page
```

As you can see I'm not unnesting hits after FROM clause but to get landing page I'm using a subquery. I'd like to add calculation of sessions for specific stages of shopping behavior funnel as well, for instance:

```
count(distinct case when hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' then concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime as string)) else null end) as sessions_with_product_views,
```

but to do it I'd need to unnest hits first. In this case I'm struggling to add the landing page as a dimension, I tried to use FIRST_VALUE OVER session id but analytics function is not allowed in the GROUP BY.

Is there a smart way to have landing page dimension and sessions for specific shopping behavior stage in the same query?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found a solution:

```
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN ( SELECT ecommerceaction.action_type FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE ecommerceaction.action_type = '2' LIMIT 1 ) = '2' THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS sessions_with_pdp_views,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN ( SELECT ecommerceaction.action_type FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE ecommerceaction.action_type = '3' LIMIT 1 ) = '3' THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))
    ELSE
    NULL
  END
    ) AS sessions_with_add_to_cart,
```